# ColdFusion 8 Applications Taking Forever To Start

Tags: windows, coldfusion, windows-server-2003, coldfusion-8, fw1

Lately I have been finding that some of the ColdFusion applications on my production server are taking forever to start.  Most of the applications are Mura websites, and one thing that I found across all of the applications is that they are FW/1 bases.  Not sure if FW/1 has anything to do with the problem.  I can't find anything in the logs, and I am not sure where else to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As found on the Google Groups forum for FW/1

> Make sure that report execution times is turned off in the CFAdmin.